# Can an employee (in Australia) be terminated if they refuse to allow their employer to look though a phone that is not used for business?

Tags: termination, legal, privacy

I know that generally in jobs where you have access to a computer and the internet any storage device plugged into a company PC or any online account you access on a company PC with the company's internet connection can be subject to monitoring and examination.

However recently I was asked to hand over my personal Mobile Phone so that my employer could view text messages and files which I do not use for work, I may use at work for emergency calls, does not get connected to a company PC (rather I recharge via a battery pack I carry with me) and no one except my employer has the number for (only because he requested it as a secondary call number in case he could not reach my landline).

I was told I had to allow this. when I tried to bring up the contract I signed and pointed out the same thing I mentioned in the first paragraph my employer said

> searching the contents of a mobile is the same as searching though your bag to see if you have stolen any company property, which is outlined in your contract. if you continue to refuse you're employment here may be subject to termination.

I can understand bags but electronic devices can obtain anything unless it's been transmitted to it via some sort of connection which my phone has made none. I also carry a laptop which I use by itself on it's own battery because it's a hassle to get the cable around to a powerpoint but now I am afraid that it might be targeted too, while I have nothing to hide which could see me get into trouble professionally I have some erotic fiction on my laptop I write at home, while i wouldn't be embarrassed if my employer read it i suspect he will misunderstand because of their content and as I am a casual employee I can be terminated without notice.

I don't even know why this has started happening as I was sick the day before. so I am wondering, in Australia can an employee be terminated for refusing to allow an employer to search though their phone (or laptop) that has had no connection to any company resource?

Comment: I'm in Australia, and this sounds like it may be exceeding their mandate.  As far as I'm aware, even the police must show cause and have a warrant before they can search your property.  However, I am not a lawyer, and I _strongly_ recommend that you talk to one to see where you stand.

Comment: Can information count as "company property" in your line of work? Then you don't need to plug your phone, for example, you could have taken a picture of a screen or (if you don't have a camera) copied some info in a text message. Note that this is only a possible explanation for his request, it does not mean that it is or isn't legal.

Comment: You need the advice of a lawyer, not some random strangers on the internet, so voting to close as off topic.

Comment: To know the answer you need to look carefully at your contract and local laws. However, if you just don't want it searched, you could try some alternatives: Don't bring it to work. Bring a cheap phone instead and allow them to search that. Change the UI language of your phone to something strange (e.g. Korean) and then allow them to search it. Encrypt sensitive information in your phone, and then allow them to search it. Refrain from taking your phone out while at work (so presumably they wouldn't request to search it in the first place).

Comment: @JaneS Checks and balances on police investigations are typically *much more strict* than what the general public can get away with. The police also do that without permission, while the issue here is whether a company can make giving permission a condition of employment. An employee can always refuse to show his phone; whether his company can fire him over that refusal is a question for the lawyers.

Comment: @Lilienthal Please be aware that Australian law is _very_ different to the US, including what the police can and cannot do.

Comment: @JaneS I imagine it would be but I was speaking of a general trend in most Western countries. And the American and Australian legal systems do share a common ancestor. As an example: just like on TV Australian police [require a warrant to search your phone](https://www.qld.gov.au/law/crime-and-police/being-arrested-and-police-custody/being-searched/).

Comment: If you were sick the day before, then it means your company is worried that you might have been at an interview with another company. Possibly, your call log and your personal email may have been (or will be) compromised, along with your address book and any picture you may have on your phone. That being said, I am absolutely horrified for you and I do hope that you take the time to consult an actual lawyer.

Comment: Please also note that if you delete nude pictures or erotic fiction from your phone or from a computer, they actually don't get deleted. I am sure you knew that already. Just know that with SD memory, this is actually much much worse since a manufacturer takes care not to overwrite a particular point in memory too many times (unless absolutely necessary) to avoid shortening the life of its hardware.

Comment: On second thought, if the lawyer says you can't refuse without losing your job, I would demand to watch them while they're looking through your phone. After all, if someone were to look through my carry-on bag, I would expect to be able to watch them closely. And if for some reason, they want to make a copy of your phone's content, then I'd refuse that part. And you could even ask to video record them while they're searching through your device. Or perhaps even say, ok, tell me what you want to see, I'll help you with your search, but that phone stays within my physical hand at all times.

Comment: Also, you could argue that it wasn't made clear what information they wanted to look at, and whether or not a digital copy would be made, and that since your phone contains your credit card numbers, private financial information, private information about your medical records, and private personal information about your sexual preference & orientation, that you wanted to get clearer guidelines on what records they would look at and what records they would ignore.

Comment: And you could further argue that for security reasons, they should install private lockers (that each employee could use with their own private padlock) at each entrance, to not only enhance security, but also minimize the privacy intrusion on each employee should employees desire to put their device in their locker during work (instead of having them subject to searches).

Answer (score -4):

You could suggest to your employer that you will put the phone in a sealed bag and hand it over to your employer, that you will press criminal charges if that bag is opened without your permission, that you will talk to a lawyer specialising in employment law, and that you expect your employer to pay the cost of the lawyer.

And if anyone other than you looks at the phone, it will not be your employer, but an independent third party which is given a list of items to look for, to which you agree, and which will under no circumstances tell the employer anything about the contents of the phone except whether these items are present or not.

The "it's not different from searching your bag" is complete and utter nonsense. For example, in the USA the police isn't allowed to search the contents of your phone anymore without a warrant, while they can be allowed to search your bag - exactly because your phone can contain *everything* about your private life.

Comment: (1) US rules aren't particularly relevant in Australia (2) There are generally completely different sets of rules for what the state, in its position of power, can do without a person's consent - vs. what conditions a person can voluntarily agree to as a condition of employment.